# How to use group by and where clause with left outer join in Hive

Tags: join, hive, bigdata

I have to join two tables using left outer join method in Hive. Please find my table details and required output below,

Apologize for big explanation. I gave all the information for more clarity in my doubts.

**Table1 columns:**

```
date1, srcid, claimno1  

Date1        srcid    claimno1

31-01-2015   ABC      432

31-01-2015   ABC      451

31-01-2015   ABC      435 

01-02-2015   ABC      451
```

**Table2 columns:**

```
date2,claimno2,amount

Date2        claimno1  amount

31-01-2015   432       150.51

01-02-2015   451       250.61

31-02-2015   451       320.72

01-02-2015   432       381.65
```

**Required Output:**

```
Date1        srcid    claimno1     amount

31-01-2015   ABC      432          381.65

31-01-2015   ABC      451          250.61

31-01-2015   ABC      432          381.65

01-02-2015   ABC      451          NULL
```

**Condition:**

> 1) from table1 need to select the record with date as 31-01-2015
>
> 2) from table2 need to select the record with date as 01-02-2015

**Assumption:**

1) claimno1 from table1 is not unique and occur many time for same date1

2) claimno2 from table2 is unique for particular date2

**Doubts:**

1) Do I need to give all the selected columns in GROUP BY ? (else getting SemanticException error)

2) What is the difference when i used the same condition  in WHERE clause and ON clause?

I have used below queries but couldn't able to get required output,

```
SELECT 
    a.date1, a.srcid, a.claimno1, b.amount
FROM
    table1 a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tableb ON (a.claimno1 = b.claimno2)
WHERE
    a.date1 = '31-01-2015'
        AND b.date2 = '01-02-2015'
GROUP BY a.date1 , a.srcid;
```

**FAILED:** SemanticException [Error 10002]: Invalid column reference 'claimno1'

```
SELECT 
    a.date1, a.srcid, a.claimno1, b.amount
FROM
    table1 a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tableb ON (a.claimno1 = b.claimno2)
WHERE
    a.date1 = '31-01-2015'
        AND b.date2 = '01-02-2015'
GROUP BY a.date1 , a.srcid , a.claimno1;
```

**FAILED:** SemanticException [Error 10002]: Invalid column reference 'amount'

```
SELECT 
    a.date1, a.srcid, a.claimno1, b.amount
FROM
    table1 a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tableb ON (a.claimno1 = b.claimno2)
WHERE
    a.date1 = '31-01-2015'
        AND b.date2 = '01-02-2015'
GROUP BY a.date1 , a.srcid , a.claimno1 , b.amount;
```

**Result:** No records selected

```
SELECT 
    a.date1, a.srcid, a.claimno1, b.amount
FROM
    table1 a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tableb ON (a.claimno1 = b.claimno2
        AND a.date1 = '31-01-2015'
        AND b.date2 = '01-02-2015')
GROUP BY a.date1 , a.srcid , a.claimno1 , b.amount;
```

**Result:** records selected but amount values are NULL

Apologize for big explanation. I gave all the information for more clarity in my doubts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider this required output: **Required Output:**

Date1      srcid     claimno1  amount

31-01-2015   ABC      432          381.65

31-01-2015   ABC      451          250.61

31-01-2015   ABC      432          381.65

Comment: Should `tableb` really be `table2 b`? Why do you need GROUP BY at all?

Comment: Sorry for typo. it should have been table2 b instead of tableb. I need to use GROUP BY because other than date fields all are placed in middle of table and not in sequence order. Here i just mentioned as example with few columns. real time the tables  will have more than 50 columns.

Comment: Can anyone help on this issue?